# I'm having trouble understanding client-side rendering in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using the new routing in Next.js 13 without the 'pages' folder.

There are two components, Parent and itsChild. itsChild uses useState and useEffect, which, according to the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#when-to-use-server-and-client-components), makes it a client-side component. However, when I try to run the application, it throws an error. It makes sense. So, I add 'use client' in Parent, and then everything works.

But it doesn't seem right to me. The itsChild component doesn't even make any fetch requests on startup. It's just a complex authentication form that makes requests and updates the state only after the user submits the form.

I think it would be correct to render the component on the server and pass the initial state to the client. However, I couldn't find anything similar in the documentation for the new routing.

Can you please advise on how to handle this? Maybe I'm misunderstanding client-side and server-side rendering.

I tried replacing the standard `useState` with my own function using closures to manage the state, but I still get an error. Even though there is no `useState` or `useEffect` in the component anymore.

I will also add that if I use my own closure-based function to manage the state, instead of useState, there are no console errors anymore because I'm no longer using useState. However, hydration errors still occur, and all I see in the browser is:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: {"source":"server"}

Call Stack
getProperError
node_modules/next/dist/lib/is-error.js (41:0)
```

I took the liberty of writing my own state function because I simply need to display either an authentication form or a registration form based on the user's selection.

Comment: Which error are you seing? Your are problaby using something that exists only on client side in the server side.

Comment: I see the error message: "You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with 'use client', so they're Server Components by default."

I tried replacing the standard useState with my own function using closures to manage the state, but I still get an error. Even though there is no useState or useEffect in the component anymore.

Comment: A form is a interactive component that depends on user action and therefore should be a client component. You can make only the file itsChild as client side with the 'use client' and let the Parent be server side.

Comment: So, is it considered best practice to make the form entirely client-side?

It does seem strange. I thought that if I don't have any data during rendering that depends on external factors, I should be able to render it on the server and then pass the interactive part (perform hydration) to the client. Well, it's disappointing that it doesn't work that way. 

Thank you for your answer

Comment: You can render pages that depends on external factors using serverside request's, in you case your component depends on client specific stuff and in certain way you are separating server and client using Parent and itsChild.